# Create user environment variable with expandable value

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables

I can create a **user environment variable** within a **Powershell script** (Windows 10) easily.

```
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('name', 'value', 'User')
```

When the variable should **contain another user environment variable** like `%OTHERVAR%;static_part`, I found that the type must be `ExpandString`. This can be done as follows

```
Set-ItemProperty HKCU:\Environment 'name' 'value' -Type ExpandString
```

So, I wrote the following code

```
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('M2_HOME', 'C:\dev\app\apache-maven-3.3.9', 'User')
# special treatment to get expandable type
Set-ItemProperty HKCU:\Environment 'PATH' '%M2_HOME%\bin;C:\Users\UID20852\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;' -Type ExpandString

Write-Host ([System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('M2_HOME', 'User'))
Write-Host ([System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', 'User'))
Write-Host
```

Output:

```
C:\dev\app\apache-maven-3.3.9
C:\dev\app\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\Users\UID20852\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
```

Everything is looking fine, both variables exist. When I open the Windows control to edit the user environment variables, I see both variables and the value of PATH is expanded. Even in `regedit` I see the type of the variables is correct.

However, when I **open a new `cmd`** and try to run a binary from `%M2_HOME%\bin` (should be on the `PATH` now), it **fails**.

To resolve the problem manually I just need to open the Windows control to edit the user environment variables, double-click the `PATH` variable, **edit nothing**, and close it again (I guess it re-writes it).

Then, in a new `cmd`, I can then run binaries from `%M2_HOME%\bin`.

**Any ideas how I can make this `PATH` variable work just through the script?**

Comment: Move `[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable ...` after `Set-ItemProperty HKCU:\Environment ...`

Comment: Why aren't you just editing the path environment variable in the way you're creating M2_HOME?

Comment: Hi @PetSerAl. Your answer works perfectly, thanks a lot. Have you got an explanation *why* that actually works in contrast to my version?

Comment: `SetEnvironmentVariable` not only update registry by also send notification about it, thus any interested application (for example `explorer.exe`) can know that them need to reread registry values. Also, AFAIK, there is no established order of user variables initialization, so dependency between per-user variables is not really supported.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: Because then it is not of type `ExpandString` and it does not work as expected because the `%...%` placeholder is taken literally and not as placeholder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kudos to @PetSerAl. His answer to **first prefix the `PATH`** variable with the placeholder string and then create the environment variable that **fulfils the placeholder afterwards** works perfectly.

```
# special treatment to get expandable type
Set-ItemProperty HKCU:\Environment 'PATH' '%M2_HOME%\bin;C:\Users\UID20852\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;' -Type ExpandString
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('M2_HOME', 'C:\dev\app\apache-maven-3.3.9', 'User')
```

If I understand his explanation in the comments correct, because the creation of the "normal" variable fires an event that immediately updates the variable with the placeholder. So it works right after the script is done.

Answer (score 0):

Any program that use **Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable()** API, like PowerShell, broadcasts [WM_SETTINGCHANGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-settingchange) that notifies system it needs to reload the environment. Then any new sessions can access the updated environment. This is not triggered when you use **Set-ItemProperty** only.

I strongly suggest the use of the **free** tool [Rapid Environment Editor](https://www.rapidee.com/en/command-line). Its command line covers any needs about *Environment Variables management* and its GUI will show every details at a glance.

Just be careful if you test its command line to NOT use **-S** parameter if you want to add a new value to an existent variable because it will override any previous values. Use -I or -A instead. And always use **-C** to avoid duplicate and invalid values. The -E parameter allow to use expandable variables.