# Setting environment variables as dependent on other env vars on windows via powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables

I want to set a variable say JAVA_HOME to dynamically assume the value of another variable say JAVA_HOME_x64..such that whenever JAVA_HOME_x64 changes and a new terminal session is created JAVA_HOME gets assigned the value of whatever is value of JAVA_HOME_x64.

In powershell , I do following...

```
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('JAVA_HOME', '%JAVA_HOME_x64%', 'Machine');
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('JAVA_HOME_x64', 'c:\myjava', 'Machine');
[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('JAVA_HOME', 'Machine') ==> returns %JAVA_HOME_x64%
```

When I open a new command prompt and type set(or echo %JAVA_HOME%), it shows me value of JAVA_HOME as  %JAVA_HOME_x64% and not c:\myjava.

However if i go to UI(as below) and manually edit(delete and recreate) JAVA_HOME and reset its value to %JAVA_HOME_x64%, and then when a launch a new command prompt/terminal session it now shows value of JAVA_HOME as c:\myjava..Why so ? Any ideas? How to achieve the same behaviour as is in UI via PowerShell commands.
[image: Set enviroment variable manually via UI]

After some investigation i realize that, registry key(in Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment) created via above powershell command line for the said variable is of type REG_SZ, while the one created via UI is REG_EXPAND_SZ. This maybe the clue

Comment: I tried looking at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607618/create-user-environment-variable-with-expandable-value, but it still does not work for me.

Comment: However pls note if i open a command prompt with "Run As Admnistrator", it seems to work all fine.

Comment: I think the question needs some correction. `JAVA_HOME` is not set to `c:\myjava` in the commands. Also, what commands do you mean "any new"? Please update the question and share more information.

Comment: @alexzelaya, i want to set JAVA_HOME  dynamically to the value of JAVA_HOME_x64 i.e if  JAVA_HOME_x64  changes in future, JAVA_HOME   will update automatically.

Comment: This is not reflected anywhere in your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, there is no native way in Windows to configure a dynamic environment variable. This has to be done via some other mechanism; GPO, Task Scheduler, etc.

Comment: this works if i set exactly the same value i.e %JAVA_HOME_x64% via UI for variable JAVA_HOME.

Comment: Kindly dedicate the necessary time to review your question. It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: The resulting registry entry would have to be type REG_EXPAND_SZ.

Answer (score 2):

The following worked..

```
Set-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' 'JAVA_HOME' '%JAVA_HOME_x64%' -Type 'ExpandString'

[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('JAVA_HOME_x64','c:\program files\Zulu\jre','Machine')
```

Comment: It is very important to set the variable used as `REG_EXPAND_SZ` using _SetEnvironmentValue_ **after** using _Set-ItemProperty_ - otherwise it won't be "refreshed" in the cmd.exe, but it will be visible as fresh in the GUI, and after exiting GUI, cmd.exe will also see the fresh value.